# Nav resize on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to this and I'm trying to have my navbar shrink once scrolling - it would be a plus if it were sticky and could pickup the body header logo when it scrolls past a certain point, but it's not necessary.

The problem is that I've tried several jquery script methods; some have completely resized the inner div which holds the logo and intro text, which should be the full page (one page navigation). Regardless, not one of the scripts actually resized the navbar.

I hope someone can help.

```
<body class="homepage">
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class id="header">

            <!-- Inner -->
                <div class="inner">
                    <header>
                        <h1><a href="#" id="logo"><img src="../../Desktop/YourCare-White.png"></a></h1>
                        <hr />
                        <span class="byline">Take Back Your Health.</span>
                    </header>
                    <footer>
                        <a href="#banner" class="button circled scrolly">it's time</a>
                    </footer>
                </div>

            <!-- Nav -->
          <header class="navheader">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <p class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="../YourCare-White-Logo.png"></a>
              </p>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span>Dropdown</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <span>And a submenu &hellip;</span>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Phasellus consequat</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Magna phasellus</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Etiam dolore nisl</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Veroeros feugiat</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://yourcare.me/join"></a>+ the Movement</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
```

```
    #header
{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}

    .homepage #header
    {
        padding: 4em 0 4em 0;
    }

        .homepage #header .overlay
        {
            content: '';
            background: #1C0920;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1.0;
            -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        }

        .homepage #header.ready .overlay
        {
            opacity: 0;
        }

    #header .inner
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4em 0 0 0;
    }

    #header h1
    {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 1em;
    }

        .homepage #header h1
        {
            font-size: 4em;
        }

        #header h1 a
        {
            color: inherit;
        }

    #header .byline
    {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #header .button
    {
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 4.5em;
        height: 4.5em;
        line-height: 4.5em;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    #header .button:hover{
        border:3px solid #35bdb2;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    }

    #header header
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #header footer
    {
        margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    }

    #header hr
    {
        top: 1.5em;
        margin-bottom: 3em;

        border-bottom-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
    }

        #header hr:before,
        #header hr:after
        {
            background: rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
        }

/*********************************************************************************/
/* Nav                                                                           */
/*********************************************************************************/
.navheader{
    background:#35bdb2;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding:20px 0;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    transition: all 350ms ease;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:20;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.nav-container{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    transition: all 350ms ease;
    position: relative;
    width:88%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
}
.nav-container:before{
    content:"";
    display: table;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#nav{
    display:block;
    float: right;
}

    #nav > ul
    {
        line-height: 0px;
        border-left: solid 1px rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
        border-right: solid 1px rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
    }

#nav > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0.5em 0 20px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    -moz-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

            #nav > ul > li.active
            {
                border-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
            }

            #nav > ul > li > a,
            #nav > ul > li > span
            {
                display: block;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #nav > ul > li > ul
            {
                display: none;
            }

.dropotron
{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.975);
    padding: 1em 1.25em 1em 1.25em;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    min-width: 12em;
}

    .dropotron li
    {
        border-top: solid 1px rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
        color: #5b5b5b;
    }

        .dropotron li:first-child
        {
            border-top: 0;
        }

        .dropotron li:hover
        {
            color: #ef8376;
        }

        .dropotron li a,
        .dropotron li span
        {
            display: block;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
            -moz-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out;
        }

    .dropotron.level-0
    {
        margin-top: 2em;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }

        .dropotron.level-0:before
        {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: -0.7em;
            margin-left: -0.75em;
            border-bottom: solid 0.75em rgba(255,255,255,0.975);
            border-left: solid 0.75em rgba(64,64,64,0);
            border-right: solid 0.75em rgba(64,64,64,0);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want a sticky navbar, or a resized navbar passed a certain point, or both?

Comment: I was actually looking for both - the navbar would resize and then pick up the logo in the inner div, resize, and float left when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 7)
        {
         document.getElementById("topp").className += " resizeing";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("topp").className = "navheader";
        }
    });
});
```

I edited your code. view this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fT9Dv/1/)

But need a little changes but I have not opportunity!

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById` with jQuery?

Comment: @RichardA I think jQuery need to `scrollTop()`

Comment: `$('#topp').addClass('resizeing')`?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I may need to add some padding, as the logo is floating towards the bottom but it definitely works well across all browsers

Comment: Sorry - what is the jquery to hide the navbar altogether in the mobile environment?

Comment: @Smcner12 I think `$('#id').hide();` or `$('#id').fadeOut();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how to do this, because you don't share all your code, but the basic idea is this:

```
<head>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> ... </style>
<script>
//approximate, edit to your specification
pos=up
$("#content").scroll(function(){
     if($(this).scrollTop() > 5 /*or some comparably small number*/ && pos == up) {
          $("#old").fadeOut(100,function() {
               $("#new").fadeIn(100)
               pos=down
          });
          $("#header").animate({
               //new css
          },100);
     } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 5 && pos == down) {
          $("#new").fadeOut(100,function() {
               $("#old").fadeIn(100)
               pos=up
          });
          $("#header").animate({
               //old css
          },100);
     }
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="homepage">
<div id="header">
     <div id="old"> ... </div> <!--The bigger header-->
     <div id="new" style="display:none;"> ... </div> <!--What you want on scroll-->
</div>
<div id="content"> ... </div>
</body>
```

I use the `pos` variable so it won't try to maximize and minimize the header at the same time.